# mysql connection lost in second successive query

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008

I have installed mysql 5.5 on a windows server and want to fetch it's data remotely.

My problem is when I send two successive query, the second one got lost connection error. when I wait something around one minutes an try again the quest successfully return results.

[image]

**Update 1**
I connect to remote database thro command line

[image]

**Update 2:**
When I try to increase MySQL time out I got MySQL gone away error.
[image]

**Update 3**
[image]

Any Idea?

Comment: Please share your schema and query

Comment: it did happened on every query which i sent. I have connect to remote database throw command line and  execute show databases;

Answer (score 1):

By default, MySQL will wait for 10 seconds before responding with a connection timeout error.

You can increase the number to 120 seconds to wait for two minutes:

```
mysql -uroot -proot --connect-timeout 120
```

you also can change the variable values, you can use the SET GLOBAL query as shown below:

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout = 600;
```

Comment: mysql -uroot -proot --connect-timeout 120 doesnot work. When I try SET GLOBAL connect_timeout = 600;  I got Mysql gone away error. see my second update in question plz.

Comment: Can you execute this command and send the result? SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout";

Comment: I did it. please see screen shot in my third update

Comment: To prevent the timeout error, you need to increase the connect_timeout and net_read_timeout variable values. I’d suggest setting it to at least 600 seconds (In your case, connect_timeout is ok). So you can try set try SET GLOBAL net_read_timeout = 600;

Comment: unfortunately not working

Comment: man, Did you get set up the variable 'net_read_timeout'  or did you have an error during the process?

Comment: I did increase time out. but still get lost connection error.